# I am doing razorpay integration in Node Js. But when i start my Node Js server with "npm start" it shows the following error in console. Help me out?

Tags: node.js, razorpay

[`enter image description hereee`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yngd0.png)

E:\myHp\RazorPayIntegration\server>npm start

> server@1.0.0 start E:\myHp\RazorPayIntegration\server
> node app.js

E:\myHp\RazorPayIntegration\server\node_modules\razorpay\dist\razorpay.js:33
throw new Error('`key_id` is mandatory');
^

Error: `key_id` is mandatory
at new Razorpay (E:\myHp\RazorPayIntegration\server\node_modules\razorpay\dist\razorpay.js:33:13)
at Object. (E:\myHp\RazorPayIntegration\server\routes\razorpayRouter.js:9:23)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
at Object. (E:\myHp\RazorPayIntegration\server\app.js:11:22)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-06-10T19_21_09_479Z-debug.log

Comment: E:\myHp\RazorPayIntegration\server\node_modules\razorpay\dist\razorpay.js:33 throw new Error('key_id is mandatory');  it is telling you that you you are not supplying key_id where it's required.

Comment: And a bit further down the log it's even telling you where in your code is the problem: (E:\myHp\RazorPayIntegration\server\app.js:11:22)

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you imported "dotenv" module. First see if your Razorpay Key Id was assigned by the value which you declared into .env file or not. Simply do `console.log(Key_id);` I guess it will return "undefined", if so then import "**dotenv**" module.

```js
const path = require("path");

require("dotenv").config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/.env") });
```

In my case the ".env" file exist inside the **src/**
I hope this will resolve your error.